# Concat column1 and column2 if column1 does not contain column2

Tags: sql, postgresql, firebird

How to get the `concat` column from `column1` and `column2`?

```
| column1  | column2 | concat
| -----------------------------
| 20KM     | NULL    | 20KM
| 20KM     | KM      | 20KM
| 20K      | M       | 20KM
```

I only want to concatenate `column1` and `column2` if `column1` does not contain `column2`.

Comment: Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: the query will be used in both postgres and firebird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Firebird, you can use a [`CASE`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-commons-conditional-case) with [`CONTAINING`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-commons-predcontaining) or [`POSITION`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-position) in combination with the concatenation operator (`||`):

```sql
case when column2 is null or column1 containing column2 then column1 else column1 || column2 end
```

or

```sql
column1 || case when column1 not containing column2 then column2 else '' end
```

See this [Firebird dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=009eae0bfb2c6e5ae1b257575892c998). Using position would be similar.

PostgreSQL doesn't have `CONTAINING`, so there you'd use `POSITION(column2 IN column1) > 0` instead of `CONTAINING` or `POSITION(column2 IN column1) = 0` for `NOT CONTAINING`:

```sql
case when column2 is null or position(column2 in column1) > 0 then column1 else column1 || column2 end
```

or

```sql
column1 || case when position(column2 in column1) = 0 then column2 else '' end
```

See this [PostgreSQL dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=73765a6ef3d318ed6b985b05b949df21). This use of `POSITION` would also work in Firebird.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
concat(column1, (case when position(column2 in column1) = 0 then column2 end))
```

Comment: Perhaps double pipe concat (and watch out for that NULL)?  _Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -804 Function unknown CONCAT_

Comment: that worked great on postgres but not on firebird; for standard sql write to accept the answer: column1 || coalesce(case when position(column2 in column1) = 0 then column2 end, '')

Answer (score 0):

I would use a CASE expression with LIKE:

```
select case 
        when column2 is null or column1 like '%'||column2||'%' then column1
        else column1||column2
      end
from the_table
```